# WSL 2 deep starting directory path

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Hello I'm beginner on WSL and I just install WSL 2 on my windows, and tried to set the starting directory with nested path like `/2023/July/Project_Folder`, currently my started directory is only on my username like `alan@alan:~$` and if I do ls that show `2023` like this [image: sample directory with ls command]

so how can I can deal with the nested path on windows WSL 2 terminal. Thanks in advance [image: starting dir config]

and I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381106/13831588) but not working

Comment: `bash.exe ~/2023/July/Project_Folder`

Comment: Also you can set it with the field shown on your screenshot, using the browse button. (WSL2 directories are also accessible in Windows)

Comment: Hi @CherryDT thank you for your answer, I've tried your answer but is show an error like this

`[error 2147942667 (0x8007010b) when launching ubuntu.exe']
Could not access starting directory "bash.exe ~/2023/July/Project_Folder"`

Comment: No that was the command line to start it directly in that directory. If you want to use the UI, you have to select the corresponding `\\wsl$` path there.

Comment: I've tried also using `\\wsl$` like example on link that i attach on my question, but still not working

Comment: Please show exactly what things you tried, otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: @CherryDT my expect `alan@alan:~/2023/Project/Remote/Company` and i tried set starting dir like this `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\alan\2023\Project\Remote\Company` but still start with user dir like `alan@alan:~$` and if i do ls, that shown like i screenshoot on my question

Comment: Hm this does look correct, so I'm not sure what's going wrong then. Perhaps you should ask in [su] because this isn't really about programming. - But to troubleshoot this I wonder what happens if you open PowerShell, do `cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\alan\2023\Project\Remote\Company` and then `bash`.

Comment: hmm it works on my powershell and give the right path that you suggest to me